Configure url link generated without portal-WEBid.properties in liferay 7.4 DXP
I have version 7.4, and I see that starting with 7.2 it cannot be configured through the "portal-WebID.properties" file.
It is recommended as a recommendation to do it through the control panel of the instance itself.
How can I configure the url of the links generated by the portal from the control panel (and thus not use the specific.properties file)
Thanks!!
In the logs, it appears that you can overwrite the parameters of the portal-ext.properties file, assigning it a specific .properties in an environment variable (LIFERAY_PROPS_BY_COMPANY_WebID) .
I have created that environment variable with the url to the file, but it does not load.
I have tried through the specific virtualhost... but when browsing, the links generated are those that appear in the portal-ext.properties, of the default portal.
